# How to set mail as 'Important' of gmail using google apis in c#?

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to add mail in gmail account using google apis in c#.

```
Message f_msg = new Message();
f_ReqforMail = m_MailService.Users.Messages.Insert(f_msg, "me");
```

How to set that f_msg mail object as 'Important'?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `Message`? could you please include more code?

Comment: My guess you should add system label to message.Try to get a [list of the labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list), find [IMPORTANT](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#types_of_labels) label and its Id. Then add labels Id to [Message.labelIds](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource-representations) list

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the [MailPriority Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223213.aspx) as:

```
f_msg.Priority = MailPriority.High
```

> Specifies the priority of a MailMessage.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> You can use this enumeration to set the priority header of an email
>   message.

Comment: OP using gmail API and `Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message` do not have Priority property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`AE.Net.Mail`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AE.Net.Mail/) to Build your MailMessage Then You can Use `AE.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High` to set the Priority. Here is an example:

```
MailMessage msg = new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage
{
    Subject = "Your Subject",
    Body = "Hello, World, from Gmail API!",
    From = new MailAddress("[you]@gmail.com"),
    Importance=AE.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = client.GetMessage(uid);
bool isHighLight = message.RawFlags.ToList().Contains("Flagged") ? true : false;
```